# Is it possible to send an email with MySQL trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have searched over the network about the email trigger in database. Yes, I have found a lot of website which uses trigger to send email. However, most of the website is just teaching people to use the SQL-server trigger...

But I currently am using phpmyadmin (MySQL), I have applied those method in MySQL but it doesn't work.

My question is so simple: How can I make a trigger a to send an email in phpmyadmin (MySQL)?

Somebody says that PhpMyAdmin does not support this out-of-the-box. You need access to your MySql server to create a UDF to send the actual e-mail.
From here: [Check this out.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/sending-email-using-mysql-database)

The code below is only used in SQL-server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER leave_system.email ON leave_system.leave_request
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT day_in_advance FROM leave_request WHERE day_in_advance <= 0)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'whoever@yourcompany.com', 
          @profile_name = 'default',
          @subject = 'Someone was speeding', 
          @body = 'Yep, they sure were.';
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: what have you done so far?? show you code/ triggers...

Comment: Check the updated question above.

Comment: the best practice is to store it to a table and make a small program to check the table and send it regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't.

This capability does not exist.

Technically... if you know how to send email from a command line, you could conceivably use [`lib_mysqludf_sys`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) to spawn a shell from a trigger and send the mail, but this code is old and appears to be unmaintained.  It is, as I recall, somewhat tricky to compile and perhaps a bit unstable.

If you know how to code in C, you could write your own UDF.

The conventional wisdom is that triggers are not really the best place to send email, since (among other reasons) if the database transaction that triggered the mail is rolled back, the mail obviously can't be un-sent.

If you were using Aurora, a MySQL-compatible database engine from Amazon, you could use the [Aurora Lambda integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Lambda.html) to send email from triggers, but this capability only exists in Aurora.